# Production build overrides my style in .css node

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, build, dev-to-production

I am using style.css where I have some CSS styles like

```
.Sidebar-img-22 {

    width: 200px !important;

}
```

And there I called

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.jsx";
import RtlLayout from "layouts/RTL.jsx";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";

import css from "assets/css/style.css";

import "assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.5.0";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/rtl" component={RtlLayout} />
      <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When I run in console

```
npm run build
serve -s build
```

my style in this style.css is not built. Maybe I have this CSS in the wrong file?

Comment: please post in the `build` script mentioned in `package.json`, if you are using `webpack` add https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/ to the `webpack.config`

Comment: I have problems with webpack.config.js I need this put on the root directory or webpack module directory? In package.json is webpack not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your root component? Did you import style.css in that?

Comment: yes and works for npm start, but when I do npm run build is not used. Some ideas? Please...

Comment: Can you show the file where you are using style.css

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
  import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

  import AuthLayout from "./layouts/Auth.jsx";
  import RtlLayout from "./layouts/RTL.jsx";
  import AdminLayout from "./layouts/Admin.jsx";

  require("./assets/css/style.css");

  require("./assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.5.0");

  const hist = createBrowserHistory();

  ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/rtl" component={RtlLayout} />
      <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

install sass-loader to the project

```
$ npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

Update the sass-loader to webapck bundling

Webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    // ... 
    module: {
        rules: [
           // ... 
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass|sss)$/;,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {loader: 'css-loader'},
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
};
```